# Listing all subpages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

trying to get my head around this one. I'm sure it's a simple solution. I am using the following script to get generate my navigation. Works fine and lists all the children of the parent, but as soon as I navigate to one of the children it obviously doesn't work.

```
<?php
  $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');
  if ($children) {
?>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I have a separate template for the children, so I just need to modify the scope so instead of child_of... it's something like all_children_of...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a version of the List Sub-Pages example from the [wp_list_pages Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages). The next example, "List subpages even if on a subpage", is what you need if I'm understanding you correctly.

```
<?php
if($post->post_parent)
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
else
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
if ($children) { ?>
  <ul>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Phil

Comment: Yup, I got some tips on the Wordpress board as well that put me on the right path which helped me figure it out. Thanks for the help!

    `<?php
     $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0');
     if ($children) {
      echo $children;
     }
     ?>`